# how use Repeaters using a single XMLDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need your help please. I have this xml file which I need to read and diplay it , here is My xml :

```
<tarification cle="979987abdcad675e13e016a6ud4777782">
    <gamme reference="new-securite-sante">
        <tarif formule="NS1">24.02</tarif>
        <tarif formule="NS2">26.64</tarif>
    </gamme>
    <gamme reference="new-equilibre-sante">
        <tarif formule="125">27.95</tarif>
        <tarif formule="150">34.95</tarif>
        <tarif formule="200">41.70</tarif>
    </gamme>
    <gamme reference="new-full-sante">
        <tarif formule="125">33.21</tarif>
        <tarif formule="150">38.71</tarif>
        <tarif formule="200">44.92</tarif>
    </gamme>
    <gamme reference="new-performance">
        <tarif formule="125">36.45</tarif>
        <tarif formule="150">43.33</tarif>
        <tarif formule="200">48.17</tarif>
    </gamme>
</tarification>
```

and the code  is :

```
<asp:XmlDataSource
    runat="server"
    id="XmlDataSource2"
    DataFile="myfile.xml" />

 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server"  DataSourceID="XmlDataSource2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="" runat="server">                        
                  <h2>Formule : <%# XPath ("@formule") %>'></h2>                        
                  <h2 class="buy"> <%# XPath ("tarif") %>"    
                  <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>   
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I want my result is like this :

```
<div>
    <h2>Formule : NS1</h2>
    <h2 class="buy"> 24.02 <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Formule : NS2</h2>
    <h2 class="buy"> 26.64 <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Formule : 125</h2>
    <h2 class="buy"> 27.95 <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong? Please correct me.

---

hier is the correct code , code c#

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.Load("http://xxxx-xmlfile.com");

    XmlNodeList nodes =
    doc.SelectNodes("tarification/gamme/tarif");
    rpMyRepeater.DataSource = nodes;
    rpMyRepeater.DataBind();
```

---

```
 <div>
    <h2>Formule :  <%#((System.Xml.XmlNode)Container.DataItem).Attributes["formule"].Value %></h2>
    <h2 class="buy"><%#((System.Xml.XmlNode)Container.DataItem).InnerText%> <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>
</div>
```

And it work like a charm :)

Comment: What results are you seeing?  You can improve your question:  http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the "formule" attribute is on the "tarif" object, not the "gamme" object.  So you could change it:

On your XMLDataSource, add the XPath property:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource
runat="server"
id="XmlDataSource2"
XPath="/tarification/gamme//tarif"
DataFile="myfile.xml" />
```

Then change your template:

```
<h2>Formule : <%# XPath ("@formule") %></h2>                        
<h2 class="buy"> <%# XPath (".") %>
```

Or you could change your data to have them both at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! In the repeater change the XPaths in Itemtempalte. It should look like:

```
<h2>Formule : <%# XPath ("tarif/@formule") %></h2>                        
<h2 class="buy"> <%# XPath ("tarif") %><sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>
```

And here's generated html:

```
<div>
    <div id="Repeater3_Div1_0">                        
        <h2>Formule : NS1</h2>                        
        <h2 class="buy"> 24.02 <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>   
    </div>                
    <div id="Repeater3_Div1_1">                        
        <h2>Formule : 125</h2>                        
        <h2 class="buy"> 27.95 <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>   
    </div>                
    <div id="Repeater3_Div1_2">                        
        <h2>Formule : 125</h2>                        
        <h2 class="buy"> 33.21 <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>   
    </div>                
    <div id="Repeater3_Div1_3">                        
        <h2>Formule : 125</h2>                        
        <h2 class="buy"> 36.45 <sub>€/ Mois</sub></h2>   
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks , i Have the correct code above :)